# How to send an email in utf8

Tags: php, email, utf-8, sendmail

i want to send message of this email in utf8 coding ..

what can i do for this

```
include 'functions.php';
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    $cap=strtoupper($_POST['cap']);

    $error = '';


$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL,$subject,$message,
        "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

what can i send this in utf8 ?

Comment: dont use mail() its very limited use one of the libraries that interfacing directly with the mail server. [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) of [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the encoding in the email headers, like so:

```
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL,$subject,$message,
        "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's utf8_encode function. Like so:

```
$message = utf8_encode(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
```

This will store the string utf8 encoded in your $message variable or any other for that matter.

**Edit**:

If you use the swiftmailer library, it will default to utf8 encoding.

Comment: It might be a little more work than just encoding the message. The other arguments and mail headers need to be encoded as well. Here's an example from a comment in the `mail()` [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): `$from_user = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($from_user)."?=";`. The user contributed notes have several examples.

Comment: True. And again, using a good mailing library will often take care of those things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the utf-8 encoding in the headers and also encode the subject, because it easily gets corrupted. I personally create my own function which also adds the ability to set the sender's adress:

```
function mail_utf8 ($to, $subject='', $message='', $from='', $header='') {
  if (preg_match("/\<html.*\>/i", $message))
    $content_type = "html";
  else
    $content_type = "plain";

  $header .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0";
  $header .= "\nContent-type: text/$content_type; charset=UTF-8";
  if ($from)
    $header .= "\nFrom: ".$from;
  mail($to, "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $message, trim($header));
}
```

Comment: PS: I know this question is 5 months old, but I don't want to write a function like this every time I want to send an e-mail. And maybe someone else will use it too.